# Zaseki - Is that a Japanese word for "seat"

Tags: word-choice, words

My Japanese book refers to it when talking about airplane seat.  But I cannot find any references to the word.  Is it the correct spelling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spelling is correct.
座席(zaseki): seat
http://jisho.org/search/zaseki

Comment: Thanks. That's strange as I also used jisho.org and it gave me the message:  Sorry, couldn't find anything matching ザせき, Zaseki or zaseki.  I notice now that it's because I typed Zaseki and not zaseki.  The former does not work but the latter does.

Comment: And ザせき is a strange mixture of katakana and hiragana, which might have confused jisho.org.

Comment: @Alan jisho.org interprets capital letters as a request for katakana specifically. It's kind of unhelpful at times, since you get katakana results from hiragana searches anyway. So it saw 'Za' and gave you ザ instead of ざ.